# Need help in identifying the design pattern using Templates

Tags: c++, design-patterns

A particular template pattern I recently encountered uses boolean type check to determine the specialization to invoke. The pattern looks quite familiar to [Policy based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) except that the Policy parameter are controlled by the data type rather than making it configurable.

```
template<
    typename Ty, 
    bool as_type = is_associative<Ty>::value,
    bool it_type = is_iterable<Ty>::value,
    bool pr_type = is_pair<Ty>::value
>
struct brackets
{
    // Any other case is an Error
};
template<typename Ty>
struct brackets<
    Ty,
    true,  //Associative
    true,  //Iterable
    false  //But not a Pair
>   {
    static const char open = '{', close = '}';
};
template<typename Ty>
struct brackets<
    Ty, 
    false, //Not Associative
    true,  //But Iterable
    false  //But not a Pair
>   {
    static const char open = '[', close = ']';
};
template<typename Ty>
struct brackets<
    Ty,
    false, //Neither Associative
    false, //Nor Iterable
    false  //Nor a Pair
>   {
    static const char open = '<', close = '>';
};
template<typename Ty>
struct brackets<
    Ty,
    false, //Neither Associative (actually don't care)
    false, //Nor Iterable
    true   //But a Pair
>
{
    static const char open = '(',  close = ')';
};
```

Can the community help me to identify the pattern?

Comment: Why do you care if it has a name?

Comment: Why do you care? Don't obsess over design patterns. Maybe this isn't 100% conformant to some strict list of design patterns that some hotshot wrote in a book. So what? Does it work? Is it clear what it's doing? Is it easy to maintain? Yes? Then move on.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The reason I do care is because with a name in place, its easier to search, communicate, document and improve (if required).

Comment: @Abhijit: Easier to pigeonhole and focus on marketing buzzwords over actual code quality, you mean

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is most closely related to the [type traits technique](http://books.google.com/books?id=aJ1av7UFBPwC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=type+traits+design+pattern&source=bl&ots=YSaLXwVe81&sig=yhJFjZpCPKeKoum4kVEiXdgxTIc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=n2LvU9-_COzksAT-yIFA&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=type%20traits%20design%20pattern&f=false) identified by Alexandrescu in his [Modern C++ design](http://erdani.com/index.php/books/modern-c-design/).

This class makes compile-time decisions based on the type parameter, customizing the code based on properties of `Ty`.

Comment: I am not sure if I can agree with you on this, but thanks any way for your answer.

Comment: What you describe is a fundamental fact of templates. I don't think you can call it a "pattern"...